# Count specific data number over total data number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the specific data number over total data number but I don't know how.

I'm stuck with just the total data number.

```
<?php
$result_total = mysql_query("SELECT count(1) FROM myTable");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_total);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Data: " . $total;
?>
```

I just want the result like be:

Desired Output:

```
Data: n of m
```

Comment: "the specific data number over total data number" - can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: @halfer i want to display the number of data like 1 of 10, one as the specific data number and 10 as the total data number. :)

Comment: Note that a single row of data usually doesn't know its position in a resultset. There are two broad ways to fix this: get all rows in an array and use the array position as `n`, or record the `n` value in the row itself. If there are a lot of records (a large `m`) then you can do the first approach with pagination (i.e. `LIMIT`).

Comment: @RyanVincent the data item would be courses. i want to display it as (i.e. Course: 1 of 10) data rows are: courseID, course, description.

Answer (score 0):

Your select should be

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change sql to

```
$result_total = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM myTable");
```

Comment: How is this different from the original statement that the question has, aside from count(*) and count(1)? Would you mind to elaborate how this fixes the problem being asked about?

Answer (score 0):

So n is your actual item. You have to count only items which are before it plus itself. Let's say you have ordered list by id. n is I'd if your item. Your query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE id <= n
```